# Bottom up tree traversal

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6, tree

I would be really thankful if you could explain to me how to traverse this tree (preferably in javascript):

[image: binary tree]

in such order: 1-3-8 | 4-6-3-8 | 7-6-3-8 | 13-14-10-8

The mocked data can look like this:

```
let tree = {
  'parent': {
    'immediate child': {
      'post immediate child'
    }
    'second immediate child': {
      'second post immediate child'
    }
  }
}

function goUpTheTree(tree) {

}
```

Any help would be very appreciated...

Comment: How (i.e. in what data structure) is the tree stored? You should give a little more information and also show some effort on your own.

Comment: Ok, some updates :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you could store the path of the nodes and if a node is found without any left or right branches, you take the path as value.

```js
function getBottomUp(node, path) {
    path = [node.value].concat(path || []);
    if (!node.left && !node.right) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(path));
        return;
    }
    node.left && getBottomUp(node.left, path);
    node.right && getBottomUp(node.right, path);
}

var tree = { value: 8, left: { value: 3, left: { value: 1 }, right: { value: 6, left: { value: 4 }, right: { value: 7 } } }, right: { value: 10, right: { value: 14, left: { value: 3 } } } };

getBottomUp(tree);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still traverse the tree top-down. Simply remember the nodes on your way and when you reach a leaf node, output all those nodes in reverse.

```js
var tree =  {
 "value": 8,
 "left": {
  "value": 3,
  "left": {
   "value": 1,
   "left": null,
   "right": null
  },
  "right": {
   "value": 6,
   "left": {
    "value": 4,
    "left": null,
    "right": null
   },
   "right": {
    "value": 7,
    "left": null,
    "right": null
   }
  }
 },
 "right": {
  "value": 10,
  "left": null,
  "right": {
   "value": 14,
   "left": {
    "value": 13,
    "left": null,
    "right": null
   },
   "right": null
  }
 }
}

function goUpTheTree(node, pathFromRoot) {
    //add the current node to the path
 pathFromRoot.push(node.value);
 if(node.left == null && node.right == null) {
  //this is a leaf node
  //print the path in reverse
  pathString = "";
  pathFromRoot.forEach(function(element) { pathString = element + " " + pathString; });
  console.log(pathString);
 }
 if(node.left != null)
  goUpTheTree(node.left, pathFromRoot);
 if(node.right != null)
  goUpTheTree(node.right, pathFromRoot);
    //remove the current node from the path
 pathFromRoot.pop();
}

goUpTheTree(tree, []);
```

I made the tree structure a bit more structured (i.e. every node has `.value`, `.left`, and `.right`). But it is basically the same as your definition.